# How to use ORM in Spring Framework...?

Tags: java, spring, orm

How to use ORM in Spring Framework...? Give me Clear Example...

Comment: Your name suits !

Comment: and the ever going mantra - what have you tried, what doesn't work, ..... (in other words, we don't do 'give me teh codez')

Comment: Give me a clear question... lol

Comment: @Gopi - harsh - we should be welcoming to newcomers.

Comment: You can also go for Spring ORM, Hibernate, IBatis etc.  Each has its own pros and cons.

Answer (score 5):

The most widely used ORM tool with Spring is Hibernate.  Here's the [section from the Spring manual about Hibernate integration](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/orm.html).